# Remapping SHIFT + SPACE to an underscore (_)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, speed, keyboard-layout

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121760/remap-keyboard-combinations-not-just-single-registry-values) and was so excited when I found out I could remap my whole keyboard with a really simple Microsoft product called [Keyboard Layout Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=8BE579AA-780D-4253-9E0A-E17E51DB2223&displaylang=en).

**My problem:** [Keyboard Layout Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=8BE579AA-780D-4253-9E0A-E17E51DB2223&displaylang=en) doesn't allow me to modify the space bar with any "shift state" keys (e. g., <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>).

[image: Characters assigned to the SPACE KEY in any shift state must be spacing characters]

I want to remap <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to an underscore (`_`).

This would be really helpful for me, because my database names are all formatted with underscore separators (e. g., `this_is_a_database_name`), and I think it'd be faster with this key combination than <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is possible with [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com):

1. [Download](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/) and install the latest version.
2. Create a new script called `underscore.ahk` with your favorite text editor.
3. Write the following in the file and save it:

   ```
   +Space::Send _
   ```
4. Double-click the file to run the script.
5. If you wish, copy the script (or a link to it) in the `Startup` folder.

Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> now inserts an underscore.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think you could help me with [this similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/420134/when-caps-lock-is-pressed-space-bar-returns-underscore)?

Comment: Here is the key list: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm it contains `LShift` and `RShift`, among other keys. Now press *Any* key. ;)

Comment: I would like `_` to be fired on `space + shift` instead of OP's request. With this solution "I_get sentences that look this, see what I_mean?" but in order to handle that, I think I will need to modify spacebar's key to fire on key up instead of the default key down.

Comment: @CSharper: The space bar is not a modifier key, so while what you're going for should be possible, it won't be a one-liner. I don't have Windows anymore, so I won't be able to help. Sorry.

Comment: This gave me an error when running the script. Changed it to `+Space::Send "_"` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had been looking for a solution for this for a while, but didn't want to download AutoHotkey. I found that Microsoft publishes a Windows extension for super users called [PowerToys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/awake) that includes a Keyboard Manager that can facilitate the shortcut.

Example setup in Keyboard Manager:

[image: Example setup in Keyboard Manager]

The upside is that this program has some other cool things that you might enjoy, but make sure you take the time to go disable things you don't want.