# When caps lock is pressed, space bar returns underscore

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, speed, autohotkey

**Basically, what I'm looking for is:** when <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is on I want <kbd>Space</kbd> to return `_` and I want <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to return .

**Detail:** This is kind of a continuation of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/419736/remapping-shift-space-to-an-underscore) I asked about the remapping the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> keys to be an underscore (<kbd>_</kbd>). I got a great answer but I've found it to be a bit complicated especially when I have a lazy pinky that doesn't like to take itself of the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key in time for me to hit the <kbd>Space</kbd> key. So now I'm wondering if anyone knows of a solution to make it so the <kbd>Space</kbd> key could remap to underscore when <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is turned on. And, even better, if <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is on and I hit the <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> combination it will force a space character. Does that make sense? Go ahead and ask for clarification.

Oh, by the way, the solution for the question I asked earlier may have the power to do this. It's called [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com/). If that'll do it, then I'm totally happy with that! Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### AutoHotkey script:

```
+Space::
state := GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")
if state
    SendPlay {Space}
else
    SendPlay _
return

Space::
state := GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")
if state
    SendPlay _
else
    SendPlay {Space}
return
```

#### What it does:

- If <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is **not** active:

  - <kbd>Space</kbd> inserts space.
  - <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> inserts underscore.
- If <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is active:

  - <kbd>Space</kbd> inserts underscore.
  - <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> inserts space.

If you want <kbd>Space</kbd> to behave normally when <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is **not** active, just eliminate the first block.

#### How to use:

1. [Download](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/) and install the latest version.
2. Save the above script as `underscore.ahk`, using your favorite text editor.
3. Double-click the file to run the script.
4. If you wish, copy the script (or a link to it) in the `Startup` folder.

#### How it works:

- `+Space:: ... return` executes `...` when <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> is pressed.

  `+Space:: ... return` executes `...` when <kbd>Space</kbd> is pressed (without modifiers).
- `state := GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")` checks if <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is active.

  - If it is, `state` is `true` and the block after `if state` gets executed.
  - If it isn't, `state` is `false` and the block after `else` gets executed.
- `SendPlay X` inserts the character (sequence) `X`.

  You cannot use `Send` here, since it would trigger the script recursively, resulting in an infinite loop.
- `return` terminates the script at the current point.

  The second `return` is optional, the first isn't. Without the latter, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> would cause **both** blocks to get executed.

Comment: @kentcdodds: You have to **replace** the previous script with this one.

Comment: Do you think you could edit the answer to remove the part with capslock off and shift+space inserts underscore? Part of my problem is I have a lazy pinky, so when I'm chatting or typing normally I accidentally insert an underscore. So basically, I want normal functionality when caps lock is off. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried the script several times with a few variations and it seems to just turn my space key functionality off entirely...

Comment: @kentcdodds: I've tried both versions (with and without the first block), and they work fine. Close AutoHotKey completely and load just this new script to make sure the old script isn't running anymore. They won't work together.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Space::
state := GetKeyState("CapsLock", "T")
if state
    Send _
else
    Send {Space}
return
```

The above answer didn't work for me either. This worked however.