# Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator doesn't accept ZWNJ (U+200c) as white space character

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm using Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4 to create a custom Persian keyboard layout.
I want to define `Shift` + `Space` as `ZWNJ` ('‌' - U+200c) character like Persian (Standard) layout. However, when I want to build DLL and setup package, it doesn't accept `ZWNJ` as white space character. Here is the error in log file:

> ERROR: 'VK_SPACE' in Shift State 'Shift' must be made up of white space character(s), but is defined as '‌' (U+200c) instead.

How should I solve this problem? Is there any alternative software?

Comment: maybe look at https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/wiki/Keyboard-Manager-Overview

Comment: @KetZoomer This one is good too however as I said in a comment for second answer, I want to create a standalone keyboard layout (not dependent on third-party softwares)

Comment: yes, but that does not appear to be possible :(

Comment: Check out this [link](https://www.dntips.ir/post/377/%D9%81%D9%82%D8%B7-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%B7%D8%B1-%DB%8C%DA%A9-%D9%86%DB%8C%D9%85-%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%84%D9%87)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any attempt in the Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator to map the
<kbd>Space</kbd> key to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
results in the following error message:

[image]

This is a limitation by Microsoft, perhaps worried about a user creating
an unusable keyboard layout. It was already noted in a
[post](https://superuser.com/questions/419736/remapping-shift-space-to-an-underscore)
dating from 2012 and hasn't changed since.

A solution must then come from a third-party product that gets the typed
keys before Windows, such as
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following one-line AutoHotkey script will send the Unicode key `200C`
when <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is pressed:

```
+Space::Send {U+200C}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However ,I don't want my keyboard layout to be dependent on a third-party software.

Comment: In [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/419736/remapping-shift-space-to-an-underscore) from 2012 MKLC was unable to map any combination involving Space. If the latest version did not improve since then, you still have my answer.

Comment: I have looked more into the problem, I even installed MKLC, and I can state that it cannot do what you want. With only Windows utilities you cannot solve this problem.

Comment: If you are looking for a way to fix MKLC, that isn't within the powers of anyone who is not a Microsoft developer.

Comment: Isn't there any other software which does the same (create an installable keyboard layout which isn't depending on any third-party software after installation)?

Comment: I checked already the ones I know, and they can't do Shift+Space either. I don't know why Space is a problem for the keyboard-layout programs. BTW, AutoHotkey is very versatile and can do much beyond key mappings, I count it as one of my best applications.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use any additional software. You indeed can setup `U+200C` as your defined character in MSKLC, BUT you will have to set it up as a dead key. Thus, set up the key as the usual `U+0020` character, but enable the dead key feature. Therein can you set up any character you want, even if it is not a space. I have set up my space key to render `U+2011` (non-breaking hyphen) with AltGr (Ctrl+Atl). The only disadvantage is that you will have to press it twice in order to get your character rendered.

Tell me if `U+200C` works as well.

[Give a look at and mimic what I did with my custom layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrPCK.png)